# How to route traffic to the internet, on an EC2 Ubuntu VPN concentrator?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, routing, router

I have a functional VPN network on EC2, but I can't initiate traffic to the internet from the web server(s), although they can serve requests.

The AWS setup if the following:

- 2 Elastic IPs (`eiplb` and `eipvpn`)
- EC2 machine (`myvpn`), with public `eipvpn` address, private IP 10.1.2.16, acting as VPN server; `Source/Destination Check` is disabled
- EC2 machine (`myweb`) without public IP, private 10.1.2.32, acting as web server
- (Application) Load Balancer, with public `eiplb` address, sends requests to `myweb`
- VPC (`myvpc`) 10.1.2.0/24
- Subnet 10.1.2.0/25, associated to `myvpc`
- Internet Gateway (`myigw`), attached to `myvpc)
- Route table (10.1.2.0/24 -> local, 0.0.0.0/0 -> `myigw`)

The current outcome is:

- the VPN server works; I can authenticate to it, then access `myweb`;
- the load balancing/app serving works; I can send HTTP requests on `eiplb`, which are served by `myweb`
- the `myvpn` machine can initiate connections to the internet

The problem is that `myweb` can't initiate connections to the internet.

For reference this is the iptables setup on `myvpn`:

```
# everything `ACCEPT`
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.2.3.0/24 ! -d 10.2.3.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.1.2.16
```

This is the routing table on `myweb`:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.2.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.2.0        *               255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

What's the simplest way to allow `myweb` to initiate connections to the internet?

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong. I can't comment on iptables, not familiar with it. What is the VPN server used for, and is anything routed to it? You'll want to trace where packets are going. [VPC Flow Logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/flow-logs.html) will let you do this. [CloudCraft](https://cloudcraft.co/) is a good free diagramming tool that would make this setup easier to explain.

Comment: It's been a bit of a mistery; I've also tried to add a NAT gateway, but couldn't connect as well. I ended up assigning public IPs (which I tried to avoid).

Comment: A NAT gateway, or instance? If you added a NAT instance it'd be interesting to see if it could ping it, and then get out to the internet using it. If you added a nat gateway and it didn't work that points to routing IMHO.

Comment: Gateway, as I needed a managed (highly available) service, sorry!